# Skydrive sync REST API

Tags: onedrive

I have read the docs for `SkyDrive` REST APIs but didn't find any API using which i can sync with the `SkyDrive`, without recursive polling the folders for update check.

Is there any API to get only the update for a user Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A commonplace reality of epistemology is that...
**It is typically much easier to prove that something exists than to prove that it does not exist**

Never the less I can say with a high level of confidence that the official REST API for Skydrive doesn't include a way of getting a list of updated documents for synchronization purposes.
Furthermore I didn't see any evidence of a non-supported/non-official API that would serve this purpose and by observing the way the Windows Client for SkyDrive interacts with the server (within limit of fair-use reverse engineering), it appears that the synchronization is done by reviewing the directory tree rather than getting a differential list.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the closes you can go is: *Get a list of the user's most recently used documents*

> To get a list of SkyDrive documents that the user has most recently
>   used, use the wl.skydrive scope to make a GET request to
>   /USER_ID/skydrive/recent_docs, where USER_ID is either me or the user
>   ID of the consenting user. Here's an example.

```
GET http://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/skydrive/recent_docs?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```